# Why is my JMeter executed Add not showing in LDAP

Tags: ldap, jmeter

I am currently testing an LDAP system using Jmeter.

The standard LDAP template in JMeter is pretty much setup and I just needed to fill in my username and password, specify a host and DN to connect to.

I have gotten to the point where all my tests return a 200 OK.
But to verify the Add actions are actually working I am looking around in my LDAP instance, but I can't find the users created by the Add action from JMeter.

Are these users supposed to be created and visible in my LDAP instance?
Why can't I find them?

Comment: It's difficult to identify your problem without additional information.
Could you show your testplan, requests?

Comment: Hi Vadim,

I have simply loaded the JMeter LDAP template, it contains pre-set samplers that have no specific configuration set, purposely filling in an incorrect username in my credentials config has taught me these samplers perform CRUD actions on enumerated accounts with the TestUser prefix.